# 1 == 0 in (0,1) is False; why?

Tags: python

How does Python parse the first of the following three expressions? (I expected it to be the same as the second, since `==` and `in` have the same precedence.)

```
>>> 1 == 0 in (0,1), (1==0) in (0,1), 1 == (0 in (0,1))
(False, True, True)
```

Comment: The confusion is a common one and finding the canonical is always going to be hard as the search terms involve punctuation that most search engines ignore. Your post can help provide additional keywords to guide people to the canonical, however. I'd keep it.

Answer (score 5):

See the [documentation of comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons): they are chained rather than grouped. So `1 == 0 in (0,1)` is equivalent to `(1==0) and (0 in (0,1))`, which is obviously false.

Comment: sort of ... its more equivelent to `False in (0,1)` but still true

Comment: @JoranBeasley Incorrect. `False in (0,1)` yields `True`, as shown in the question.

Comment: OK OK you win I was wrong... I didnt read the answer close enough :P